# Can you send a notification via a different controller action besides the create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getstream-io

I'm trying to send a notification via a different action other than `create`. My Article model has a `published` boolean attribute/column, and currently I have it so it only sends a notification when an article is created AND published is true.

Here's my `article.rb`:

```
  def activity_actor
    user
  end

  def activity_object
    self
  end

  def activity_notify
    return if user.followers.empty?
    user.followers.map(&:id).map do |user_id|
      StreamRails.feed_manager.get_notification_feed(user_id)
    end
  end

  def activity_should_sync?
    published
  end

  def activity_target
    return "article_#{Time.now}"
  end
```

I would still like the original functionality (article is created and `published` is true), but I would also like a notification sent when an article is already created and `published` is updated to true. Therefore, I'd need to send a notification via the `update` action.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to manually send notifications or to control the trigger that sends notifications. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manage this manually within your `update` action, I think.

`feed = StreamRails.feed_manager.get_user_feed` will return an instance of `Stream::Feed` which you can then call `feed.add_activity(activity_data)`. If you send the same `foreign_id` and `time` as the original activity, we'll perform an upsert and update the original activity. This does not trigger a new notification if you're updating a previous activity though, so you'd need to manually send that activity to those other notification fields as well.

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks for the answer. I don't think I need to update an original activity, so that's good news. I'm simply creating a new activity whenever `published` is set to true. From what I'm understanding it would make sense to add an activity to a user's feed via `get_user_feed`, but I actually don't have any users following other users' feeds. Therefore no one gets notifications from another user's feed. I would need to send a notification only to the followers via the notification feed and not via following a user's feed.

Comment: I looked at the gem's library and I'm thinking the solution for this type of use-case would be in `sync_policies.rb`. If there was a third module called `SyncUpdate` where in the `self.included` method, it would have `          base.after_commit :add_to_feed, on: :update` instead of `on: :create`. Of course it would also have the `add_to_feed` method like the `SyncCreate` module.

Comment: The issue with `on: :update` though would be that it would run every time something was updated. Not sure how to get around checking for a specific boolean attribute. Maybe `on: :update_attribute` would work? You would then have to either pass in the attribute that you're updating as a check. That seems like too much of a hack though.

Comment: So if I understand your use case, you want to add activities to a feed which may or may not have this `published` flag, but activities which do have this `published` flag set you want to send another activity to a different feed? If so I think you still want to look at the `feed_manager` to get a reference to that other feed and add an activity as I've described. We offer no SDK/API control for that sort of check.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks anyway. I'll figure out a workaround. Basically, I want to add activities to specifically a notification feed when an article switches from  `published == false` to `== true`. Or in more plain terms, when a user publishes an article, send notifications to all their followers saying they published an article.